# Checking the balanced bracket in given expresion using stack

Tags: java, stack

**I am getting wrong output in one of the tests cases( *exp={ a + [ b - c } ] * ).What should be the correction in the below code to get the correct output? I have created two stacks. one for opening bracket and other for closed bracket and checking the bracket one bt one from the top.**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Solution {
  
    public static boolean checkBalanced(String exp) {
        
        Stack<Character> stack=new Stack<>();
        Stack<Character> stack1=new Stack<>();
        int l=exp.length();
        //inserting the open bracket from back into the stack
        for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
        {
            if(exp.charAt(i)=='[' || exp.charAt(i)=='{' || exp.charAt(i)=='(')
            {
                stack.push(exp.charAt(i));
            }
            
        }
        //inserting the close bracket from back into the stack
        for(int i=l-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            if(exp.charAt(i)==']' || exp.charAt(i)=='}' || exp.charAt(i)==')')
            {
                stack1.push(exp.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        int s1=stack.size();
        int s2=stack1.size();
       //checking the size of stack that whether they are equal or not
       //if sizes are not equal then bracket is not balanced.
        if(s1==s2)
        { int s=stack.size();
          for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
          {     //checking the brackets that whether they are equal or not
              if(stack.peek().equals(stack1.peek()))
              {
                  stack.pop();
                  stack1.pop();
              }
          }
         return true;
            
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually only one stack is needed. You push the opening braces onto the stack. When you run into a closing brace, this should be balanced by the open brace on the top of the stack. If the stack was empty, or the wrong type of brace was there, then throw an exception or otherwise indicate an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one stack
Once getting an open bracket, push it into the stack
Once getting a close bracket, check if the top of the stack is the corresponding one. 
I'm not familiar with java, so I will give you a python example

```py
stack = []
# traverse the exp
for i in range(len(exp)):
    if exp[i]=='(' or exp[i]=='[' or exp[i]=='{':
        stack.append(exp[i])
    elif exp[i]==')':
        # check the top of the stack
        if len(stack)>0 and stack[-1] == '(':
            stack.pop()
        else:
            return False
    elif exp[i]==']':
        # check the top of the stack
        if len(stack)>0 and stack[-1] == '[':
            stack.pop()
        else:
            return False
    elif exp[i]=='}':
        # check the top of the stack
        if len(stack)>0 and stack[-1] == '{':
            stack.pop()
        else:
            return False
# if stack is empty, return True
return len(stack)==0
```

Answer (score 0):

A simplified solution using one stack

```
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Stack;
    
    public class BalancedExpression {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
            var expression = "";
            System.out.println(isValid(expression));
    
    
        }
    
        private static boolean isValid(String expression) {
            var bracketsMap = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
            bracketsMap.put('(', ')');
            bracketsMap.put('{', '}');
            bracketsMap.put('[', ']');
            bracketsMap.put('<', '>');
            var openingBrackets = "({[<";
            var closingBrackets = ")}]>";
    
            var stack = new Stack<Character>();
            for (var ch : expression.toCharArray()) {
                if (openingBrackets.contains(ch + "")) {  // if it is a opening pair
                    stack.push(ch);  // push it into stack
                } else if (closingBrackets.contains(ch + "")) {  // if it is a closing pair
                    if (stack.isEmpty()) {  // if there are no opened brackets
                        return false;  // the expression is invalid
                    }
                    var lastOpenedBracket = stack.peek();
                    var lastOpenedBracketClosingPair = bracketsMap.get(lastOpenedBracket);  // get last opened brackets closing pair
    
                    if (lastOpenedBracketClosingPair == ch) {  // if current character  is the closing pair of last opened bracket
                        stack.pop();  // close the bracket and remove it from stack
                    } else {  // if both are not equal
                        return false;  // the expression is invalid
                    }
                }
            }
    
            return stack.isEmpty();  // if there are still opened brackets it is invalid
    
        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There were two problems in your code

1. check `if(stack.peek().equals(stack1.peek()))` is not correct, those two stacks has different brackets, e.g. '[' and ']', and these two characters you cannot compare with `equals` as imply '[' not equal to ']'.

So you need to introduce more smart check, I can suggest you to write a function like

```
    public static boolean bracketsMatch(Character openBracket, Character closeBracket) {
        return (openBracket == '[' && closeBracket == ']')
                || (openBracket == '{' && closeBracket == '}')
                || (openBracket == '(' && closeBracket == ')');
    }
```

to compare pairs of brackets and the change a check into:

```
if (bracketsMatch(stack.peek(), stack1.peek())) {
```

2. The next problem is missing `else` statement for the `if` mentioned above. So if brackets are not the same then just return `false`, otherwise your programm will return `true` after the loop

```
if (bracketsMatch(stack.peek(), stack1.peek())) {
    stack.pop();
    stack1.pop();
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Here is the whole code block:

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class Solution {

    public static boolean checkBalanced(String exp) {
        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
        Stack<Character> stack1 = new Stack<>();

        int l = exp.length();

        //inserting the open bracket from back into the stack
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if (exp.charAt(i) == '[' || exp.charAt(i) == '{' || exp.charAt(i) == '(') {
                stack.push(exp.charAt(i));
            }
        }

        //inserting the close bracket from back into the stack
        for (int i = l - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (exp.charAt(i) == ']' || exp.charAt(i) == '}' || exp.charAt(i) == ')') {
                stack1.push(exp.charAt(i));
            }
        }

        int s1 = stack.size();
        int s2 = stack1.size();

        //checking the size of stack that whether they are equal or not
        //if sizes are not equal then bracket is not balanced.
        if (s1 == s2) {
            int s = stack.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
                //checking the brackets that whether they are equal or not
                if (bracketsMatch(stack.peek(), stack1.peek())) {
                    stack.pop();
                    stack1.pop();
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static boolean bracketsMatch(Character openBracket, Character closeBracket) {
        return (openBracket == '[' && closeBracket == ']')
                || (openBracket == '{' && closeBracket == '}')
                || (openBracket == '(' && closeBracket == ')');
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("correct = " + checkBalanced("( exp = { a + [ b - c ] } )"));
        System.out.println("incorrect = " + checkBalanced("( exp = { a + [ b - c } ] )"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static boolean checkBalanced(String s) {
    Deque<Character> stack = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0, size = s.length(); i < size; ++i) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        switch (c) {
        case '(': stack.push(')'); break;
        case '[': stack.push(']'); break;
        case '{': stack.push('}'); break;
        case ')': case ']': case '}':
            if (stack.isEmpty() || stack.pop() != c)
                return false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return stack.isEmpty();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM**:
their is logical error
your stack s1 = ('{' , '[') and s2 = ('}',']')
so when you pop both will match.

**SOLUTION**: You have  check s2 from bottom instead of top(you  can use queue) or you can use only first stack s1 and when ever you encounter closing bracket just pop one bracket and check whether they are paired or not.

P.S: I have just mentioned logical error